# Difference between MPC and outsourced computation

Tags: multiparty-computation

I am reading an introductory paper on multi-party computation (MPC), and it makes a distinction between outsourced computation and MPC.

> In an outsourced computation, one party owns the data and wants to be
>   able to obtain the result of computation on that data. The second
>   party receives and stores the data in an encrypted form, performs
>   computation on the encrypted data, and provides the encrypted results
>   to the data owner, without learning anything about the input data,
>   intermediate values, or final result. The data owner can then decrypt
>   the returned results to obtain the output.

After reading this, I  found outsourced computation and its difference to MPC is not quite clear. In MPC, parties can send their encrypted data to a trusted third-party to compute a result that then gets delivered back to them. This seems like what was described above, no?

My thoughts to justify the difference include:

- Perhaps outsourced computation only involves two parties, the data provider and the data processor
- Perhaps outsourced computation does not require the individual to send encrypted data to the second party

In summary, what is the difference between MPC and outsourced computation?

Comment: I think it should be `secure outsourced computation`, outsourced computation can be performed without security. In MPC setting, some parties can be honest, some semi-honest, some malicious and some covert adversaries.

Comment: By "send encrypted data", do you mean: requires a confidential channel between the parties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About outsourced computing: under a security viewpoint, there is no challenge in trusting a thirty party and give him all responsibility on doing the task in secrecy and return the output the the parties. Trust a central party is all everyone doesn't want. So security isn't a problem when you trust someone.

Secure multi-party computation: in the most classical view, with secure MPC we have *n* parties entering their correspondent inputs (in secrecy), and get their correspondent output(s) (when it is the case) (in secrecy). The challenge here is the inexistence of a trusted party, and all we want is that a **protocol** makes the role of that trusted party, giving the guarantees that trusted party could provide.

For example, we can consider some security level of a digital version of an election: think about some computer that we can trust, in a hypothetical *idealized world*, realizing the election function. Your challenge is: how can you construct a (distributed) **protocol** that runs among the parties, and that gives all the security guarantees that trusted computer could provide to the electors.